# Storing Data in Stucts Containing Arrays in a Header File

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, header-files

I am currently trying to store information that is input from a function to a struct declared in my header file and utilize it within the main file. I cannot use struct arrays because I am not allowed to allocate memory.

**header file**

```
#ifndef HOMEWORK_H_
#define HOMEWORK_H_

typedef struct
{
        int CourseID[25];
        char CourseName[100][25];
}Course;

void NewCourse(void);

#endif
```

**My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Homework.h"

void NewCourse()
{
        int i;
        int CNumber = 0;

        Course storeC;

        for(i = 0; i < 0; i++)
        {
                if(storeC.CourseID[i] == 0)
                {
                        if(storeC.CourseName[i] == NULL)
                        {
                                int CNumber = i;
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("%d\n", CNumber);
        printf("Please enter the course's ID number: ");
        scanf("%d", &storeC.CourseID[CNumber]);
        printf("Please enter the course's name: ");
        scanf("%s", storeC.CourseName[CNumber]);
}
```

and my main does not really apply since the problem lies within storing the data.

A few things to keep in mind is I must utilize a separate file for my functions and I must use a header file for my structs.

I know my for loop to determine where in the array may not be effective, but I am not so worried about it as of right now.

> My question is how do I store the data from this function to the
>   header file?

**Update**

I changed the main function to fit everything else and I end up with this error now.

> a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a
>   statement

The code in main is:

```
switch(Option)
                {
                        case 1:
                        Course c = NewCourse();
                        printf("%d\n%s\n", c.CourseID[0], c.CourseName[0]); // For testing purposes
                        break;
```

What is causing the error because it says it stems from line 29 which is the `Course c = NewCourse();`?

Comment: "not allowed to allocate memory". You realize that the stack is a region of memory that gets allocated, right?

Comment: I mean using Malloc or Calloc

Comment: Then you meant that you aren't allowed to dynamically allocate any memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `NewCourse` to return a `Course`.

   ```
   Course NewCourse(void);
   ```
2. Change the implementation to:

   ```
   Course NewCourse()
   {
      int i;
      int CNumber = 0;

      Course storeC;

      ...

      return storeC;
   }
   ```
3. Change `main` accordingly.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       Course c = NewCourse();
   }
   ```

**PS**

You said,

> I cannot use struct arrays because I am not allowed to allocate memory.

I assume that to mean that you cannot use dynamic memory allocation. If you are allowed to create an array of `struct`s in the stack, you can simplify your code by using:

```
typedef struct
{
   int CourseID[25];
   char CourseName[100];
}Course;

void NewCourse(Course course[]);
```

and in `main`, use:

```
Course courses[25];
NewCourse(courses)
```

**In response to your update**

You needed to add a scope block `{ }` around the code as follows:

```
int main()
{
    {
       Course c = NewCourse();
    }
}
```

This should resolve your error and allow your code to compile.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that earlier but failed to change main as well.

Comment: Now my only problem is I get "a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement" as an error from the main where I set Course c = NewCourse();

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you have an error in manipulating the CNumber Variable. It is declared twice, with different scopes:

`int CNumber = 0;` // the first definition with the scope of the NewCourse Function

Then inside the test, with a block scope:

```
  if(storeC.CourseID[i] == 0)
  {
      if(storeC.CourseName[i] == NULL)
      {
          int CNumber = i; // block-scope. This is not the same CNumber Variable (todo: Omit int)
          break;
       }
  }
```

As a result, when you reference it later in

```
printf("%d\n", CNumber);
printf("Please enter the course's ID number: ");
scanf("%d", &storeC.CourseID[CNumber]);
printf("Please enter the course's name: ");
scanf("%s", storeC.CourseName[CNumber]);
```

It will be always reference the function scope variable, which is always be zero.

Solution: omit the int declaration inside the test:

```
  if(storeC.CourseName[i] == NULL)
  {
     CNumber = i;
     break;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I honestly was oblivious to that int before the CNumber. I don't even know why I included it, but thank you for catching that.

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped.